# Why is the German "qu" pronounced as "kv"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, phonetics

Why is the German "qu" pronounced as "kv"? Most of the languages I know of pronounce "qu" as "w" and/or "kw". What's the history behind this oddity?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples? From the top of my had I can only think of words where it's pronounced *kw* (*ku*) or *k*: quasi, Quarks, quarz, Quiche, Antiquariat, Quorum, Quanten...

Comment: Apart from "Quiche" all these words are pronounced with /kv/, not /kw/.

Answer (score 10):

Why do you think it's an oddity?

The sound [w] (as in the English words "wind" [wɪnd] or "weep" [wiːp]) does not exist in German language. The most similar sound that exists in German is [v].

And in English I didn't find any word where "qu" was spoken other than [kw]:

- conse**qu**ence [ˈkɒnsɪ**kw**ɛns]
- **qu**ick [**kw**ɪk]
- re**qu**est [ɹɪˈ**kw**ɛst]
- **qu**ality [ˈ**kw**ɒlɪti]
- **qu**arter [ˈ**kw**ɔːtə]
- s**qu**ad [s**kw**ɒd]

So, beside the general usage of [v] instead of [w] the German pronunciation is the same like in English.

Comment: In words that come from French the English use [k] e.g. "quiche". And then there's "quay", pronounced [ki:]

Comment: Plus there's "queue' [kju:]

Comment: It is the same in German. Foreign words are usually pronounced as in their original language (or at least people try ...).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Don't forget Latin. "qu" is definitely not pronounced as in the modern Romanic languages. But I am  not sure  whether it is correctly pronounced as [kv] or [kw].

Comment: @PiedPiper "quay" is pronounced [ke:], and it comes as the German loanword _Kai_ (also pronounced in German way [kai]), as in _Kaigasse_, _Mayburger Kai_, etc.

Comment: @PiedPiper Oh, sorry, I misread. You wrote "the English use", and I wrote about the German usage.

Answer (score 2):

Middle High German had a phoneme /w/, usually written “w”, and did not have the sound [v]. In New High German this /w/ survives in a very small number of words (I can think of “blau” and "grau"); otherwise it shifted to /v/, but retained the old spelling with “w” or “qu”. The development of “qu” to /kv/ is thus exactly parallel to the development of “w” to /v/.

Comment: I thought they were talking about *kfark*. Köllsch retains the /w/ I guess.